# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, g++, clang

I have some problems when I try to run my main.cpp file, only with mac gcc/clang/g++ compiler.

Here is the code:

*random.h*

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void initialize();
float randomFloat(int, int, int);
```

*random.cpp*

```
#include "random.h"

void initialize() { srand(time(NULL)); }

float randomFloat(int min, int max, int p) {
  int intPart = rand() % (max - (min - 1)) + min;
  if (intPart == max) {
    intPart--;
  }
  float decimal = (float)(rand() % (int)pow(10, p)) / pow(10, p);
  return intPart + decimal;
}
```

*util.h*

```
#include <iostream>

int askInteger(const char *, bool);
```

*util.cpp*

```
#include "util.h"

using namespace std;

int askInteger(const char *message, bool onlyPositive) {
  int number;
  if (onlyPositive) {

    while (cout << "Type a correct " << message << ": ",
           !(cin >> number) || number < 0) {
      cerr << "Input error, try again. \n";
      if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
      }
    }

  } else {
    while (cout << "Type a correct " << message << ": ", !(cin >> number)) {
      cerr << "Input error, try again. \n";
      if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
      }
    }
  }
  return number;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "random/random.h"
#include "util/util.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, min, max, p;

  n = askInteger("numbers quantity", true);
  p = askInteger("precession", true);
  min = askInteger("min value (included)", false);
  max = askInteger("max value (included)", false);

  while (max <= min) {
    cout << "max value should be greather than " << min << "\n";
    max = askInteger("max value (included)", false);
  }

  initialize();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << randomFloat(min, max, p) << "\n";
  }
}
```

**And It gives me this result:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "askInteger(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2552a5.o
  "initialize()", referenced from:
      _main in main-2552a5.o
  "randomFloat(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2552a5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**vscode applies this command to run the code:**

```
Random-Numbers % cd "/Users/user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/" && g++ main.cpp -
o main && "/Users/user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/"main
```

**Here is my project structure:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwATX.png)

## *I have tried already*

```
gcc *.h
```

```
gcc -c *.h
```

```
g++ *.cpp
```

```
g++ -o *.cpp
```

```
g++ -c *.cpp
```

Comment: It looks like neither are _util.cpp_ and _random.cpp_ compiled nor are _util.o_ and _random.o_ linked in.

Comment: @Armali I've tried already, I wrote:  `g++ -o random.cpp` in: `user@MacBook-user random` (path were random.cpp is located), but it gives me: `clang: error: no input files`

Comment: that doesnt address what Armail is suggesting, that you need to compile all the resources the main function is depending on first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AT LAST! I could run it**

*c++ vscode default commands doesn’t match with g++ mac compiler*

c++ vscode default command to run main:

```
d "/Users/user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/"main
user@MacBook-Pro-de-user Random-Numbers % cd "/Users/user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/
user/Downloads/Random-Numbers/"main
```

you have to compile by terminal with the command:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-user Random-Numbers % g++ -o ./main.exe random/random.cpp util/util.cpp main.cpp
user@MacBook-Pro-de-user Random-Numbers % ./main.exe
```

[image: evidence]

[commands g++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compiling-with-g-plus-plus/)